# Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism, then $im(f)$ is a subgroup of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism, then $im(f)$ is a subgroup of $H$. I know this is true, my question is:  Is $im(f)$ necessarily a normal subgroup of $H$? If not, can you provide a counterexample, and when that will be true?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take any group with a non-normal subgroup as $H$. Let $G$ be an isomorphic copy of that non-normal subgroup. Then the injection of $G$ into $H$ is the example you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the case.

Take $f:\{\pm 1\} \to S_3$, with $f(-1) = (2\ \  3)$.
$im \ f$ is not normal since $(1 \ \ 2)(2 \ \ 3)(1 \ \ 2)=(1 \ \ 3)$.